# How to have an individual notification for every message?

Tags: applications, notifications, notification-bar, push-notifications

Similar to the iPhone, is there any way I can get a separate, individual notification for every SMS, update, (any sort of notification)?

This is not specific to SMS, but rather to any app.

Currently, my phone will chunk notifications by the app and once I get 5+ notifications from an individual app, my phone will chunk the notifications together and I can no longer see the notifications unless I deliberately click on the notifications.

Comment: That's probably going to depend largely on what version of the OS you're running.

Comment: I too want an answer to this. I just switched from iOS to the Samsung S8, running Android 7, and this is one of the most annoying things about my phone. If I receive a bunch of important notifications, it tells me about a few of them and hides the rest - the only way to know that there are more is some tiny number. I also have 3 email accounts setup, and the notifications are grouped per account, so I only see one or two emails per account, with another tiny number indicating that there are more. Grouping notifications is good in theory, but can be horrible in practice.

Comment: Is this specific to sound notifications or status bar notifications? I believe few third-party applications are capable of doing this, @Tal

Comment: The notifications on the [lock screen](https://www.androidcentral.com/sites/androidcentral.com/files/styles/larger_wm_blw/public/article_images/2014/06/Android-L-lockscreen-2.jpg?itok=zksRb2tC). Mine doesn't look exactly like that, but same idea - instead of showing every message individually, it shows that one email account has 2 messages, another has 6 messages, and that tiny +2 at the bottom seems to indicate that there's 2 more notifications hidden.

Answer (score 1):

**Customising android to mimic ios notification style**

While **android os** is still lagging behind **ios** in terms of personalisation and notfications there are a dozen of applications
that come close to mimicking this behaviour, in my research I managed to grab just a few:

---

1. [Defumblr Smart Lock](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.delvv.lockscreen)

[image]     [image]

**Key Features:**

1. Defumblr highlights your important messages in a unified messaging interface
2. Launch your most used apps with Quick App Launcher
3. Sync the Lock screen Calendar and Alarm with your Android system.
4. Organize critical to-do items right on your lock screen with a customized To-Do List widget
5. Get glanceable forecasts with the Weather widget
6. Organize all your important notifications and messages in one place
7. Personalized configuration options including layout, color schemes and backgrounds
8. Secure your phone with password or PIN protection
9. Customize which apps to feature on your lock screen

---

2. AcDisplay

[AcDisplay](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.achep.acdisplay&hl=en) 
 is a good example that completely replicates Apple’s functionality.

> It uses the sensors on your device to know when to wake up, saving you
>   from hitting the home button or power button on your device.  It’s
>   also customisable, so you can adjust which notifications you want to
>   show up, plus use some power saving settings and dynamic backgrounds.

Screenshots:

[image]

---

3. [SlideLock](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.slidelock)

> is a simple and clean locker with powerful notification features.

Features :

- Simple and clean android locker replacement
- Swipe the screen to the right to unlock, swipe it to the left to access the camera
- Actionable detailed notifications, double tap to open, swipe to dismiss
- PIN and pattern security
- Screen wakes up for a short time when receiving a notification, allowing you to perform a quick check without having to touch the device
- Custom settings for each app (sound, vibration, ...)
- Notification banners when your device is unlocked
- Low battery usage

Screenshots:

[image]  [image] [image]

Hope this helps